# how to mkview *.cpp file if and only if a fold is made within the file?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, gvim

My init.vim code

```
cd ~/Documents/cp
set backupdir=~/Documents/cp/vimtmp//
set directory=~/Documents/cp/vimtmp//
set undodir=~/Documents/cp/vimtmp//
set viewdir=~/Documents/cp/vimtmp//

augroup remember_folds
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinLeave *.cpp mkview
  autocmd BufWinEnter *.cpp silent! loadview
augroup END
```

When i save a .cpp file in nvim, everytime like this `~=+Desktop=+cp=+A.cpp=` 
4KB file is created in vimtmp folder. 
And I don't want that.

**How can i make my vim to do a mkview if and only if a fold is made?** 
otherwise vim won't if a fold is not made

I searched online but couldn't find any solution. Perhaps you folks can help me out this feature.

Comment: Detecting folds is non-trivial. But the idea would be “if has folds then mkview”. See https://github.com/benknoble/vim-auto-origami for one way to detect folds

Comment: does vim-auto-origami make some files to save the folds or mkview or something?

Comment: No, it detects folds and sets the foldcolumn variable automatically. But it contains a function to determine if any folds exist

Comment: take no offense.. but is it possible to use your plugin scripts (autoload and plugin file) in vimrc/init.vim ?

Comment: As long as you respect https://github.com/benknoble/vim-auto-origami/blob/master/LICENSE you can do what the license says you can

Comment: I couldn't manage to merge the scripts of autoload and plugin. perhaps you could help me. and of course,, the credit everything is yours

Comment: I don’t have time to walk you through how to put vimscript in a file for your config, but you can use `~/.vim/autoload`, etc. Your entire vim directory is on runtimepath, so you can use all the standard directories...